# unwanted space after a div that had top: -7

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the unwanted whitespace in following example?

Note 1. that there should not be any red color, because #red is parent of two other #green and #blue.

Note 3. both #green and #blue have unknown height.

Note 2. #blue have an extera "top: -10px" css property, so it comes 10px up, but the parent element(#red) will not resize verticaly to fit new positions

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #red{width: 500px;background: red;height: auto;}
    #green{width: 500px;background: green;position: relative;float: left;}
    #blue{width: 500px;background: blue;top:-7px;position: relative;float: left;}
    .clear{clear: both;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="red">
        <div id="green">Green<br>Green<br>Green<br>Green<br>Green</div>
        <div id="blue">Blue<br>Blue<br>Blue<br>Blue<br>Blue</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see no white space in your code...  http://jsfiddle.net/vGG3a/

Comment: @Sparky672: He means the extra 7px of red at the bottom of the blue box, which is created by moving the blue box up 7px with a relative position.

Comment: What browser?  Are you using a valid `doctype`?   Does your page validate?

Comment: @animuson, ok, yes.  From the description, I'm not sure what he wants to achieve.  Why not just remove the `top:-7px;` then?  http://jsfiddle.net/vGG3a/1/

Comment: @Sparky672: I can't remove top:-7px. because I need to use animations using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you are floating things which are the same width as the parent. Also, using `position: relative` here is not at all necessary. Here's a much simpler way to achieve exactly what you are talking about:

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="green">
        Green<br>Green<br>Green<br>Green<br>Green
    </div>
    <div id="blue">
        Blue<br>Blue<br>Blue<br>Blue<br>Blue
    </div>
</div>​
```

```css
#red{
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
    height: auto;
}
#green{
    background: green;
}
#blue{
    background: blue;
    margin-top: -7px;
    /* Necessary so the text in #green doesn't appear over the blue background */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

[**View the jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UzPQC/)

Answer (score -1):

Add this on your div #red

top: 0;
position: fixed;